# How do I redirect all requests that contains a certain string to 404 in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to return all requests to urls that contains the string ***Histats*** to 404. How can I do that?

Comment: What pattern you are looking for /Histats/* ?

Comment: I am looking for * Histats *

Comment: `if ($request_uri ~ .*Histats.*) {
        return 404;
}`

Works fine.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I was able to solve this major headache. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747175/nginx-location-match-regex-for-special-characters-and-encoded-url-characters

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
location ~ Histats {
    return 404;
}
```

PS: [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

Comment: Thanks! I assmume that I can use | to look for different strings?

Comment: yea, but I think you need to use a block for that `location ~ (Histats|test)`